# Find minimum of the sigma

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Is there any polynomial algorithm to finding ${x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n}$ for fixed  $a_{i,j},p_{i,j},g_{i,j}$ such that minimize $\sum p_{i,j}c_{i,j}$ where :

$a_{i,j}+x_i-x_j\equiv c_{i,j} \pmod{g_{i,j}},0\leq c_{i,j} \leq g_{i,j}-1$

Comment: did you ever think about proving this is equevalent to a NP problem?

Comment: yes but I can't prove that either !

Comment: what about an approximation method to find answers?